# Mysql Between in Between

Tags: mysql, sql, between

how to select data between 2 dates in between 2 dates? for example :

```
start_date - end_date -- title

2014-01-28 2014-02-03 test

2014-02-01 2014-02-15 ests

2014-02-28 2014-03-03 sets

2014-03-01 2014-03-10 sste
```

the problem is, i want to select data between 2014-02-02 and
2014-02-28 with first three of them selected because the first three
data is included on 2nd month.

i tried this, but not works

```
SELECT title FROM my_tables WHERE start_date BETWEEN 2014-02-02 AND 2014-02-28
```

how it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two periods overlap when one begins before the other ends, and the other ends after the first begins.  Here is the correct logic:

```
SELECT title
FROM my_tables
WHERE start_date <= '2014-02-28' and
      end_date >= '2014-02-02';
```

Note that date constants need to be in single quotes.

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a0108/1) is a SQL Fiddle showing it working.

Comment: have you tried that? i tried that, but it not works, no data displayed :(

Comment: @MuhammadZaidTaufiq . . . It works.  Check the SQL Fiddle in the answer.

Comment: i don't understand about the schema in your fiddle, i think it's not same as my_table above

Comment: ehmm, sorry bro, that's my fault :) it's worked! THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Add single quote to date constant

```
SELECT title FROM my_tables WHERE start_date BETWEEN '2014-02-02' AND '2014-02-28'
```

Comment: i'm sorry, i forget it but it still not works, any other advice?

Comment: it's not error, but it's not the output what i want, i want the first three data as the output

Comment: what is datatype of start_date?

Comment: the datatype is date bro

Answer (score 0):

A date range overlaps with another when either the start or the end is within that other range:

```
given range:    |----|
range 1     |----|           overlaps with given range, because end_date is in that range
range 2            |----|    overlaps with given range, because start_date is in that range
range 3  |----|              does not overlap with given range, because both start and end date are not in that range
```

```
SELECT title FROM my_tables 
WHERE (start_date BETWEEN '2014-02-02' AND '2014-02-28')
OR (end_date BETWEEN '2014-02-02' AND '2014-02-28');
```

Comment: almost! but the output is duplicate if i use that, how?

Comment: There must be duplicate titles in my_tables. You can of course select distinct titles by using SELECT DISTINCT title from ...

Comment: I just notice there should be parentheses used. I'll update my answer.